# Send audit log to syslog server as independent stream

Tags: syslog, audit

I have a system which is currently set up via `rsyslogd` to send `/var/log/messages` to a syslog server. I also want to send the logs contained in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to the same server.

One of the easiest ways to do this is by modifying `/etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf` and changing active to `yes`. This sends a copy of the audit logs to `/var/log/messages`, which is picked up by `rsyslogd`. However, date information and hostname information is prepended to the audit message to put it in syslog format.

Is there any way to send the raw unmodified audit log to the same server on its own?